# why lpad gives strange strings in dbms_output?

Tags: oracle, plsql

i'm writing a recursive procedure to browse a tree af accounts number. each account has a account_group column which contains the id of the parent group.

I want to provide an account id and see all the account tree above him until the main account with id 0.

This procedure will help me investigate issues in an acountable application.
it's only for debugging purpose.

It reads info of the given account_id (including it's group id which is also an account), then prepare a indented string, and finally calls itself with the group_id as a parameter.

Note that the string is "back built"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ACCOUNT_DETAILS(
    i_account_id in number,
    tree in varchar2 default '',
    rlevel in number default 0
  ) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
      tree2 varchar2(2000);
    BEGIN 
      for o in ( select account_group, account_number, account_type from brr_accounts where account_id = i_account_id )
      loop
        tree2 := lpad( o.account_number, 50 - rlevel ) || '(' || i_account_id || ')' || chr(13) || tree;
        if ( i_account_id != 0 )
        then
          ACCOUNT_DETAILS(o.account_group, tree2, rlevel + 1);
        else
          dbms_output.put_line(tree);
        end if;
      end loop;
    END;
  END ACCOUNT_DETAILS;
```

If i call the procedure with the account id let's say 1258 i want the output to be similare to this (please note the indentation):

dbms_output:

```
MAIN_ACCOUNT(id 0)
 subaccountX(id 745)
  subaccountY(id 995)
   targetaccount(id 1258)
```

But i got this:

```
                                       Account A(2708)
                                        Account Y(3980)
                                         Account T(2710)
                                          Account G(4)
                               Account F(17)
                                  Account X(144)
```

to be more clear, i have prefixed each line with the rlevel and result of 50 - rlevel which is exactly what i give to lpad function:

```
tree2 := to_char(rlevel) || ' ' || to_char(50 - rlevel) || ' ' || lpad( o.account_number, 50 - rlevel ) || '(' || i_account_id || ')' || chr(13) || tree;
```

here is the result:

```
5 45                                        Nxxxxx(2708)
4 46                                         Gxxxxx(3980)
3 47                                           Sxxxx(2710)
2 48                                             Exxx(4)
1 49                                TxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxU(17)
0 50                                   1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(144)
```

As you can see, the numbers given to lpad are properly calculated (i intentionaly used a margin of 50), but the visible result isn't at all aligned with the given parameter.

is there any explaination ?

Comment: Sample data might be helpful - a [mre] will make it clearer what is happening. Is there a reason you're writing a procedure for this rather than using a hierarchical query or (if you're on 11gR2 or higher) a recursive CTE?

Comment: Thanks Alex for your feedback. I'm pretty weak with plsql so i'm using the only way i know to achieve recursive processing. I don't know what kind of sample data i could add and i don't want to extract the real business data. i was thinking my example is clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LPAD` is not the proper function you should use in your example as your requirement is not matching with it.

How `LPAD` works:
It appends the number of padding characters to the input string so that the length of the input string becomes what is given to the function as an input.

So, Consider the example below:

```
SELECT LPAD(X,10) FROM 
(select '123' AS X FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '123456' FROM DUAL) TAB

Output:

LPAD(X,10)
----------
       123
    123456
```

Here, 7 blank space is added in the first row and 4 is added in the second row. Now, the length of both the records is 10.

I hope it is clear to you now.

For your example, you should simply add the number of blanks to your string rather than using `LPAD` using following:

`rpad(' ',50 - rlevel,' ') || o.account_number`

so your code for `tree2` will become something like this

```
tree2 := 
    TO_CHAR(RLEVEL)
    || ' '
    || TO_CHAR(50 - RLEVEL)
    || ' '
    || RPAD(' ', 50 - RLEVEL, ' ')
    || O.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
    || '('
    || I_ACCOUNT_ID
    || ')'
    || CHR(13)
    || TREE;
```

Cheers!!